# PayPal express checkout add tax info

Tags: paypal

So i was integrating my app with paypal for express checkout and could not figure out how to add in my gst/hst number for Canada to the receipt.

it is mandatory if i am to charge taxes in Canadian shipment, that the gst/hst number be visible in the receipt, but cant seem to figure this out.

any help would be appreciated!

below is an example of my receipt but i want to add some additional content for the gst/hst number. where would i be able to and how.
[image]

references:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2
- [https://turbotax.intuit.ca/tips/self-employed-business-win-creating-cra-compliant-invoice-8827#:~:text=It%20is%20very%20important%20that,you%20cannot%20charge%20GST%2FHST](https://turbotax.intuit.ca/tips/self-employed-business-win-creating-cra-compliant-invoice-8827#:%7E:text=It%20is%20very%20important%20that,you%20cannot%20charge%20GST%2FHST).

## **ANSWER:**

so this is just a trick around it since i couldnt find a proper solution, but i just add in another item with the GST/HST Number. i leave the cost of it to 0 so it does not affect the total price but the buyer is still able to get the gst/hst number on their receipt.

Answer (score 0):

The `amount` key can include a `breakdown` key, which is an object of type amount_breakdown documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown

`tax_total` is the key name of one of the objects you can include in the breakdown.

The breakdown's subtotals must add up to the actual amount value.

Comment: i understand that part and was successful on doing that. but to charge taxes in canada, you need to have a gst/hst number. this number should also be visible on receipts when you charge anyone. so since i am charging taxes, to me compliant with everything i need to make visible this gst/hst number. how do i add that onto the receipts.